# Programmatically firing a client-side event

Tags: javascript, click

I have a typical ASP.NET web form application.  It has about 20 separate user controls (.ascx files), each one containing a DetailsView control.  One of the requirements of this application is that there needs to be a single Edit, Update, and Cancel link outside of those user-controls, which, when clicked, will cause each of those DetailsView objects to go into the correct mode, Edit or ReadOnly, and, if Update was clicked, do an appropriate database update.  In other words, clicking that "global" link has to programmatically fire the client-side click for each of those corresponding links that you get "for free" when you create a DetailsView or GridView.  I've tried copying the actual __doPostBack event that gets invoked when you do use one of those "internal" links, assigning it to a string, doing a Page.ClientScript.RegisterScriptBlock, then doing a LinkName.Attributes.Add("onclick", "script_string_name") -- but I just can't get it to work.  What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: `_doPostBack` is not client side -- it goes to the server.

Comment: Then I didn't express myself correctly.  I can see that the "internal" links generate a __doPostBack call, which causes the DetailsView to go into the correct mode.  That's what I want to accomplish, using a single link (or set of links) that sits on the containing .aspx page.

Comment: It sounds like you are using MVC - is it MVC or web form?  For web form just use a `asp:linkbutton` control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cd4z1zs(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It is a web form, not MVC.  Here is my code:   string script = "__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dvRecordBillingInfo$dvRecordBillingMethod', 'Edit$0');";
   
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "EnterEditMode", script);
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton) AppUtil.FindControlRecursive(this.Parent.Parent.Parent, "lnkEditAll");

   if (lnk != null)
   {
    lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "EnterEditMode();");
   }

Comment: Just use a linkbutton control

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asp:linkbutton control to do this.